# How to modify web page elements loaded in a browser

Tags: javascript, html, events, dynamic, firefox-addon

I want to associate some actions with keys (of a keyboard) and then modify the contents of a webpage loaded in the browser. For example, I'll write a firefox plugin and that would be listening to some keyboard events. Based on a key press (or something like that) I want to modify the html code of the page. For example, I would like to change the color of a link.
Any suggestions on how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The simplest way to do this would be to write a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) script, in which you'd implement the functions you wanted just like you would do it in a web page.
2. A similar solution is to write your own add-on that simply injects your code (similar to the greasemonkey script in (1)) in the page. See this very simple add-on for an example: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10275
3. If you needed full power (not limited to what the web page can do) in the shortcut handler, you could set it up in an extension (e.g. with a [<key>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/key) element and then [work with the content page from the extension code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code#Accessing_content_documents).

Comment: do you think greasemonkey could help on hiding all youtube watched videos (or simply removing the watched video screenshot so I could easily skip them but not lose access)?

Comment: @AquariusPower: I think it will; this could be posted as a question on its own, though.

Comment: I actually found a way with tampermonkey for chrome http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/149842 I am just trying to find a way to make the javascript surround the entry with the <details> tag so I wont lose access to it; as soon I can I will see if I create such a question

Answer (score 0):

I think follwing sites will be helpfull on has dom reference and next has event examples,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference
http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_examples_3.asp

You can read the elements in the page using follwing methods,
1. getElementById
2. getElementsByTagName
3. getElementByName

and using the DOM you can play with it. ex

```
//change the background of text box to red
var ele = document.getElementById('textBox1')
ele.style.background = "red";
```

Comment: The question is about a Firefox add-on, which has its own specifics.